# Describle all the projective varieties in $\mathbf{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It seems like a very stupid question: **describe all the projective varieties in $\mathbf{P}^1$.**

Since $\mathbf{P}^1$ should be the simplest interesting example we have in algebraic geometry. So I want to have a comprehensive understanding on this. My attempt:

1. Consider the affine cone, since it preserves the irreducibility. But the affine varieties in $\mathbf{A}^2$ are not simple like $\mathbf{A}^1$.
2. consider its affine open cover. But the topology on $\mathbf{P}^1$ is not the product topology of $\mathbf{A}^1\times \mathbf{A}^1$.

So I got stuck. I guess all projective varieties in $\mathbf{P}^1$ are either finite sets of points or $\mathbf{P}^1$, because I read someone says  that in the product topology $\mathbf{P}^1 \times \mathbf{P}^1$, all nontrivial closed sets are finite unions of points and lines. I am not even sure this is correct.

Comment: I know the answer immediately after I posted this... If someone wants to know, I can answer this...

Comment: You're always welcome to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 1):

We can see a non-trivial example (which can be generalized easily to any case):
$$f(x,y)=x^3+x^2y+xy^2+y^3$$ 
Assume this is an irreducible polynomial (if not, try another). And consider its zero set $Z(f)$:

1. $x\neq 0$, then 
   $$f(x,y)=0\Leftrightarrow 1+\frac{y}{x}+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^3=g(t)=0$$
   where $t=\frac{y}{x}$. So there are finite solutions for the single-variable equation $g=0$, which correspond to the solutions $[1:t]$ for the polynomial $f$ in $\mathbf{P}^1$.
2. $y\neq 0$. Similar to the first case.

Above all, all non-trivial projective varieties in $\mathbf{P}^1$ are finite sets of points.